# Large data pairwise calculation in R

Tags: r, loops, large-data, pairwise

I have a super large data frame containing nearly 5 million rows.
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axj5k.png)
then I have a char list containing around 2000 items, I need to do a pairwise(lets say one is A other is B) calculation on them, so at the end, I will have a 2000*2000 matrix containing values. The value I need is:
(#id has A and B)/ min(#id has A, #id has B)

```
load("data.RData")  
    
n = length(itemlist) # n=1831
    
a = matrix(0, n, n)

rownames(a) <- colnames(a) <- itemlist

aa = sapply(itemlist, function(x) grepl(x, data$Item))

for(i in 1:1830) {
  
  for(j in (i+1):1831) {
    
    a1 <- aa[,i]
    a2 <- aa[,j]
    a3 <- a1 & a2
    
    a[i,j] <- sum(a3) / min(sum(a1), sum(a2))  
    
  }
  print(i)
}

result <- a
```

This code works but it is super slow(take days). I was wondering if it can be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using [paralleldist](https://github.com/alexeckert/parallelDist) with a custom C++ function.

```
library(parallelDist)
library(RcppArmadillo)
library(RcppXPtrUtils)
```

I am taking as input an integer matrix with values in 0,1

```
mat <- as.integer(rnorm(10*10) > 0) |>
  matrix(nrow = 10)

mat

##>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
##> [1,]    0    1    0    0    1    1    1    1    0     0
##> [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0     0
##> [3,]    1    1    1    0    1    0    1    1    1     0
##> [4,]    0    1    1    0    1    0    1    1    1     0
##> [5,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     1
##> [6,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1     0
##> [7,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    0     0
##> [8,]    0    1    0    1    1    1    1    0    1     1
##> [9,]    1    0    0    1    0    1    1    1    1     1
##>[10,]    0    1    1    0    1    0    0    0    0     1
```

Now let's create a custom C++ function using the armadillo C++ library.

```
customDist <- cppXPtr(
  "double customDist(const arma::mat &A, const arma::mat &B) {
  double a = arma::accu(A);
  double b = arma::accu(B);
  double s = arma::accu(A && B);
  return s/(a > b ? b : a);
  }", depends = c("RcppArmadillo"))
```

Calculation using parDist is performed using multiple threads defaulting to all the cpus.

```
dst <-  mat |>
  parallelDist::parDist(method = "custom",
                        func = customDist)


as.matrix(dst)
  
##>           1   2         3         4         5         6         7         8
##>1  0.0000000 1.0 0.8000000 0.8000000 0.6666667 0.5000000 1.0000000 0.8000000
##>2  1.0000000 0.0 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.0000000 0.5000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
##>3  0.8000000 0.5 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.6666667 1.0000000 0.7500000 0.5714286
##>4  0.8000000 0.5 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.6666667 0.7500000 0.7500000 0.6666667
##>5  0.6666667 0.0 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.6666667
##>6  0.5000000 0.5 1.0000000 0.7500000 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.5000000 0.5000000
##>7  1.0000000 1.0 0.7500000 0.7500000 0.3333333 0.5000000 0.0000000 0.7500000
##>8  0.8000000 1.0 0.5714286 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.5000000 0.7500000 0.0000000
##>9  0.6000000 1.0 0.5714286 0.5000000 0.6666667 1.0000000 0.7500000 0.7142857
##>10 0.5000000 0.0 0.7500000 0.7500000 0.6666667 0.0000000 0.2500000 0.7500000
##>           9        10
##>1  0.6000000 0.5000000
##>2  1.0000000 0.0000000
##>3  0.5714286 0.7500000
##>4  0.5000000 0.7500000
##>5  0.6666667 0.6666667
##>6  1.0000000 0.0000000
##>7  0.7500000 0.2500000
##>8  0.7142857 0.7500000
##>9  0.0000000 0.2500000
##>10 0.2500000 0.0000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple approach using base R (single thread). Let's start from a boolean matrix represented as 0,1:

```r
mat <- as.integer(rnorm(10*10) > 0) |>
  matrix(nrow = 10)

##>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
##> [1,]    0    1    0    0    1    1    1    1    0     0
##> [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0     0
##> [3,]    1    1    1    0    1    0    1    1    1     0
##> [4,]    0    1    1    0    1    0    1    1    1     0
##> [5,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     1
##> [6,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1     0
##> [7,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    0     0
##> [8,]    0    1    0    1    1    1    1    0    1     1
##> [9,]    1    0    0    1    0    1    1    1    1     1
##>[10,]    0    1    1    0    1    0    0    0    0     1
```

The value `S[i,j]` representing `sum(mat[i,] & mat[j,])` is also given by the scalar product of `mat[i,]` and `mat[j,]`. Therefore, the matrix `S` can be obtained by the matrix product of `mat` and `t(mat)`:

```
S <- mat %*% t(mat)
```

The sum `C[i]` of `true` values in each row `mat[i,]` can be calculated straightforwardly:

```
C <- apply(mat, 1, sum)
```

Then, we obtain the matrix `H` where the element `H[i,j]`  is the minimum of `C[i]` and `C[j]`.

```r
H <- outer(C, C, "pmin")
```

Finally, we divide `S` by `H` to obtain the desired matrix:

```r
S/H
##>           [,1] [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]
##> [1,] 1.0000000  1.0 0.8000000 0.8000000 0.6666667 0.5000000 1.0000000
##> [2,] 1.0000000  1.0 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.0000000 0.5000000 1.0000000
##> [3,] 0.8000000  0.5 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.6666667 1.0000000 0.7500000
##> [4,] 0.8000000  0.5 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.6666667 0.7500000 0.7500000
##> [5,] 0.6666667  0.0 0.6666667 0.6666667 1.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333
##> [6,] 0.5000000  0.5 1.0000000 0.7500000 0.3333333 1.0000000 0.5000000
##> [7,] 1.0000000  1.0 0.7500000 0.7500000 0.3333333 0.5000000 1.0000000
##> [8,] 0.8000000  1.0 0.5714286 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.5000000 0.7500000
##> [9,] 0.6000000  1.0 0.5714286 0.5000000 0.6666667 1.0000000 0.7500000
##>[10,] 0.5000000  0.0 0.7500000 0.7500000 0.6666667 0.0000000 0.2500000
##>           [,8]      [,9]     [,10]
##> [1,] 0.8000000 0.6000000 0.5000000
##> [2,] 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.0000000
##> [3,] 0.5714286 0.5714286 0.7500000
##> [4,] 0.6666667 0.5000000 0.7500000
##> [5,] 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.6666667
##> [6,] 0.5000000 1.0000000 0.0000000
##> [7,] 0.7500000 0.7500000 0.2500000
##> [8,] 1.0000000 0.7142857 0.7500000
##> [9,] 0.7142857 1.0000000 0.2500000
##>[10,] 0.7500000 0.2500000 1.0000000
```

Comment: I did not quite get this one, can you pls explain it a bit more? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, the original answer was a bit cryptic. I re-edited the answer including step-by-step comments. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

That's about as good as it will get building `aa`, but the double loop can be made much faster:

```
f <- function(rws) {
  aa <- matrix(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 1831*rws, replace = TRUE), ncol = 1831)
  n <- ncol(aa)
  cs <- colSums(aa)
  a <- matrix(0, n, n)
  
  for (i in 1:(n - 1L)) {
    idx <- (i + 1L):n
    a[i, idx] <- colSums(aa[aa[,i], idx, drop = FALSE])/pmin(cs[i], cs[idx])
  }
  
  return(a)
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f(5e2), f(5e3), f(5e4), times = 1L)
#> Unit: seconds
#>      expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
#>    f(500)   1.707038   1.707038   1.707038   1.707038   1.707038   1.707038     1
#>   f(5000)  15.397640  15.397640  15.397640  15.397640  15.397640  15.397640     1
#>  f(50000) 147.445477 147.445477 147.445477 147.445477 147.445477 147.445477     1
```

This appears to be scaling pretty linearly, so I'm guessing <4 hours for 5e6 rows on a single thread with enough memory.